# 503 error in tomcat deployed in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat6

I have deployed tomcat 6.0.28 on two amazon ec2 instances and they share a common mysql 5.5 database. I have also made use of the elastic load balancer. When I run the program using the tomcat in my local machine, everything is fine.

But when i use the ones in EC2, i get the following error,

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL:.

Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i cannot find anything unusual in my log.

Comment: If I were you I would simplify.  First, get it working on your ec2 instance.  Second, add the load balancer.  Third, add your second ec2 instance to the load balancer.  If I had to guess at the problem, it would be that tomcat on ec2 doesn't have the database drivers, or the database connection is not configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Well i did find the cause of the problem. The session was not maintained because of the load balancer. It runs fine when i make use of a single instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was with sessions. I did not enable stickiness. Hence the next time the load balancer routed to a different instance. I enabled stickiness in elastic load balancer and everything is fine now.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer? This way others with a similar problem might benefit of it.

Comment: Oops!! Sorry I did not know about it.